# Lego Adventurers set with bridge, board with mountains?

Tags: set-identification

I'm looking to identify a Lego Adventurers set. At least I'm pretty sure it's adventurers, or a similar theme like Orient Express.

The set has a mountain board, with a river underneath. (If you own a LEGO curved road board, it's similar, except it has a river in place of the road and 3-dimensional mountains.) It's a very unusual piece, though it broke apart quite quickly unfortunately.

The piece also included a rope bridge.

The box had an adventurer wearing a hat swinging from a rope (?)

I don't have pix - it's a set I remember from my childhood and would love to re-buy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How 'bout *[Set #5986 Amazon Ancient Ruins](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5986-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*?

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, though the bridge looked similar. The board was 3-dimensional, that was the biggest standout of the set.

Comment: I added more detail.

Comment: Hmm... let's look again...

Comment: Amazon ancient ruins!!!! BINGO!!

Comment: The little car looks great.

Comment: Hi @TheAsh - if this has answered your question (and it looks like it has), could you click the little Tick by the up and down votes - this gives both you and Rin Rio-Oki some reputation, and lets others know that your question is solved.